# Cairo-deck isn't starting up automatically why?

Tags: 16.04, launcher, startup

This might seem to be a stupid question but I have rebooted my computer a mount of times and still cairo-deck just wouldn't start up itself!

Is anyone able to give me a hand?
I have tried right clicking blah blah and set it to launch when start-up kind of thingy.  Checking online for terminal commands and did those too but after I restarted my pc it just won't start automatically.  I have to manually open it then each time it'll ask about the GLopen question but each time I click on remember me which shouldn't even happen anymore since remember me is clicked but it just keep on happening.

Thanks in advance people

Comment: Is cairo dock listed in Startup Applications?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju ah, let me check that later today.  Starting to get used to ubuntu didn't know there's such thing available.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to:
System Tools => Preference => Startup App
Add the following:
Name: Cairo-dock
Command: cairo-dock -o
Save, that's all.

Note: the command "cairo-dock -o" lauch cairo-dock with OpenGl Enabled
If you want it disabled, just add the following:
cairo-dock -c

Cheers,
JeeT